# Rear wheel jerks and wobbles while riding

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, wobble, vibration

I bought a [Hero howler 27.5T MTB- single speed](https://www.herocycles.com/product/howler-27-5t-v-brake) two years ago.  At that time I was 120kg (265lbs) and I hadn't faced any issue while riding cycle.

Then I stopped cycling for almost 2 years. I parked it in my garage. The cycle is still in very good condition. Now again I started but I am now 130kg (287lbs).

Now the rear wheel jerks when I ride the cycle. The tire also feels pressure. It doesn't jerk when I am pedaling but jerks when I am at a very normal speed and not pedaling. I also showed it to a local shop and they told me everything is okay with the cycle.

My daddy which is a normal weight person rides it and rides it smoothly without experiencing jerk. Please guide me on what should I do? Should I ride it in this condition? Will I have any problems like the cycle breaking down or etc?? Is it normal when obese rides cycle? Please guide me.

---

There are no broken spokes and the axle not bent.

The cycle is a single gear cycle.

When I ride the rear-wheel wobbles.

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive than "rear wheel jerks"?

Comment: Is the rear wheel out of true (rim going from side to side)? Maybe because of a broken spoke? Is the rear axle maybe bent (only likely with old hubs)? Is the freehub mechanism locking up? Is shifting not working correctly? Are the brakes rubbing (maybe in combination with an out-of-true wheel?) We need more information.

Comment: If you have been using the bike at 120-130kg it is more than likely that the rear wheel has suffered over the years, out of true, bent or broken axle or that the rear end of the frame is out of alignment. Have it checked by a bicycle mechanic.

Comment: Hey, So answers are: Yes it's pedaling. And no everything is fine. No broken spoke and axle not bent. The cycle is a single gear cycle. Also when i bought i was 120kg and slowly i started losing weight and i lost till 110kg. Also cycle is properly checked and when my daddy ride on it( he is 80 kg) the cycle works perfectly fine.

When I drive rear-wheel wobbles.

Comment: @hetalgokani a photo or video of "jerking" might be useful here - one image can literally replace a thousand words of description.

Comment: Is there any hub bearing play? I can’t think of anything which would make the wheel wobble (i.e. the rim going side to side) only above a certain rider weight, then go away again (i.e. not permanent damage from the weight). With very strong riders it can happen that the wheel distorts under load because the spokes pull on it asymmetrically (I don’t think this can happen with a symmetric single speed wheel though).

Comment: Spokes can lose tension with breaking.  Tap each one and make sure they all make a 'ting' sound and not a 'thunk'?

Comment: Presumably you have you looked down, what did you see? Better yet, please video it.

Comment: What happens if you increase rear tire pressure? E.g if you have 30psi now and you increase to 35psi. I’m wondering if your tire has worn sidewalls and the difference between you and your dads weight is the critical point.